# Using fread() instead of read_table() in R for large data sets

Tags: r, data.table, bigdata, fread

I have two different folders, 'big_data' ( one ~ 2GB file) and the other 'small_data' ( ~ 6 files that ~150 MB in total).
I want to upload a data file that contains multiple header rows and whitespaces into R. the structure of the file is something like the one shown below

```
# File name
#
#@   1  "Some text"                                                   "aa"
#@   2  "Some text"                                                   "bb"
#@   3  "Some text"                                                   "cc"
#@   4  "Some text"                                                   "dd"
#@   5  "Some text"                                                   "ee"
#@   6  "Some text"                                                   "ff"

#
#
#
#

 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  
 1.000000e-03  3.727051e-04  2.532203e-04  4.736003e-04  3.727051e-07  0.000000e+00   
 2.000000e-03  2.266785e-03  1.540081e-03  2.880429e-03  2.639490e-06  0.000000e+00  
 3.000000e-03  7.538553e-03  5.121786e-03  9.579321e-03  1.017804e-05  0.000000e+00   
 4.000000e-03  1.838835e-02  1.249329e-02  2.336627e-02  2.856639e-05  0.000000e+00  
 5.000000e-03  3.703296e-02  2.516073e-02  4.705817e-02  6.559935e-05  0.000000e+00 
 6.000000e-03  2.266785e-03  1.540081e-03  2.880429e-03  2.639490e-06  0.000000e+00  
 7.000000e-03  7.538553e-03  5.121786e-03  9.579321e-03  1.017804e-05  0.000000e+00   
 8.000000e-03  1.838835e-02  1.249329e-02  2.336627e-02  2.856639e-05  0.000000e+00  
 9.000000e-03  3.703296e-02  2.516073e-02  4.705817e-02  6.559935e-05  0.000000e+00
```

As you can see, it contains 10 rows and 6 columns. The text after '#@' are the column names. I wrote the following function to import the data from the user specified folder.
It imports the data, skips the rows that contain header text, extracts the column names and removes NA columns to all files in that folder.  I used read_table() if the 'user_specified_folder' is 'small_data' and fread() if the 'user_specified_folder' is 'big_data'. It works for the former, but not the latter. There is no error with fread(), The R session memory was about 6 GB, but the imported file size was only 15 kB with just the column names.

```
imp_data <- function(user_specified_folder){
  
  # path of a single file for extracting header name
  foo      <- here::here("data",species)
  p_header <- here::here("data",species, list.files(foo)[1])
  
  # find skip value
  
  skip <- tail(grep("\\#", readLines(p_header)),1)
  
  # Get a List of all`.txt` files
  filenames <- list.files(here::here("data",species), pattern = "*.txt", full.names = T)
  

  # Load data sets
  if(user_specified_folder == "big_data"){
    
    list.DFs  <- lapply(filenames, fread , skip = skip)
  }
  
  else{
    
    list.DFs  <- lapply(filenames, read_table, col_names = F, skip = skip)
  }
  
  # name the data frame the same as file name
  names(list.DFs) <- basename(filenames)

  # extract column names from a dataset for a particular type
  rl <- readLines(p_header)
  nms <- rl[grep('^#@', rl)] |>
    sub(pattern='[^"]*"(.*)"\\s*$', replacement='\\1') |> 
    gsub(pattern='[" ]+', replacement=' ')
  
  # remove NA columns
  list.DFs <- lapply(list.DFs, function(x) x[, colSums(is.na(x)) < nrow(x)])
  
  # Apply column names to all datasets of a particular user_specified_folder
  list.DFs <- lapply(list.DFs, setNames, nms)
  
  return(list.DFs)
}
```

```
data_big_data <- imp_data("big_data")
```

How do I get the above code working with fread()?

Comment: First if your file is too big than the memory allocated then whatever means you use to read the file, you will still be unable to read the file. Consider reading chunks instead of the whole file. Also, I am not sure whether you need to read the whole file into memory. If the file has groups, read in the groups and manipulate them one at a time.

Comment: You could try with [vroom](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) (replace `fread` with `vroom`), but it's unlikely it will work if fread is running out of RAM.

Comment: @jared_mamrot I tried vroom - it seems promising - but several columns are imported as logical, instead of numeric and hence, a lot of NA values in columns. Just to preview the big_data, I went to import file from readr. The preseta are as follows and I want it like this using vroom
Skip: 64 lines, 
Delimiter: Whitespace 
First row as names is unchecked
Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: @jared_mamrot I also tried using vroom for the smaller data set- same issue with reading incorrect columns and NA values . Maybe i just need to define the arguments properly?

Comment: Another option: `arrow::read_csv_arrow`. This _lazily_ reads the file, and using `dplyr` pipes you can filter, group, mutate, and summarize (with relatively simple R expressions) before calling `collect()` which is the first time the resulting data is pulled into memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would read these files:

```
library(data.table)
filename <- 'E:/temp/test.txt'
con <- file(filename)

n <- 0
repeat {
  n <- n + 10
  header <- readLines(con, n)
  test1 <- grepl("#", header, fixed = TRUE)
  test2 <- nchar(header) == 0 #assumes empty lines don't contain whitespace characters
  if (any(!test1 & !test2)) {
    n <- n - sum(!test1 & !test2)
    break
  }
}

close(con)

header <- header[seq_len(n)]
header <- header[nchar(header) > 1]

header <- sub(pattern='[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*"', replacement='', header)
header <- gsub('"', '', header)

DT <- fread(file = filename, skip = n, header = FALSE)
setnames(DT, header)

print(DT)
#       aa           bb           cc           dd           ee ff
# 1: 0.000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000e+00  0
# 2: 0.001 0.0003727051 0.0002532203 0.0004736003 3.727051e-07  0
# 3: 0.002 0.0022667850 0.0015400810 0.0028804290 2.639490e-06  0
# 4: 0.003 0.0075385530 0.0051217860 0.0095793210 1.017804e-05  0
# 5: 0.004 0.0183883500 0.0124932900 0.0233662700 2.856639e-05  0
# 6: 0.005 0.0370329600 0.0251607300 0.0470581700 6.559935e-05  0
# 7: 0.006 0.0022667850 0.0015400810 0.0028804290 2.639490e-06  0
# 8: 0.007 0.0075385530 0.0051217860 0.0095793210 1.017804e-05  0
# 9: 0.008 0.0183883500 0.0124932900 0.0233662700 2.856639e-05  0
#10: 0.009 0.0370329600 0.0251607300 0.0470581700 6.559935e-05  0
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `cmd`-argument from `fread()`, to pre-process the file before reading.

Functionally, it reads the output of a shell command using fread. In this case, we use a grep-like command (findstr is present in all modern windows (i'm using W10) versions) to read only the lines we want to read.

On windows it works with `findstr`, on a *nix environment, you have to adapt the code below to use of `grep` or `awk`.

Possible downside of this solution: Depending on the shell-command chosen, it might make your code less portable between operating systems.

```
library(data.table)

# extract the forth column of all lines starting with "#@"
colnames <- fread(cmd = 'findstr "^#@" weird_file.csv', 
                sep = " ", header = FALSE, select = 4)

# extract all lines not startting with a "#" 
mydata <- fread(cmd = 'findstr "^[^#]" weird_file.csv', 
                sep = " ", header = FALSE, col.names = unlist(colnames) )


#       aa           bb           cc           dd           ee ff
# 1: 0.000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000e+00  0
# 2: 0.001 0.0003727051 0.0002532203 0.0004736003 3.727051e-07  0
# 3: 0.002 0.0022667850 0.0015400810 0.0028804290 2.639490e-06  0
# 4: 0.003 0.0075385530 0.0051217860 0.0095793210 1.017804e-05  0
# 5: 0.004 0.0183883500 0.0124932900 0.0233662700 2.856639e-05  0
# 6: 0.005 0.0370329600 0.0251607300 0.0470581700 6.559935e-05  0
# 7: 0.006 0.0022667850 0.0015400810 0.0028804290 2.639490e-06  0
# 8: 0.007 0.0075385530 0.0051217860 0.0095793210 1.017804e-05  0
# 9: 0.008 0.0183883500 0.0124932900 0.0233662700 2.856639e-05  0
#10: 0.009 0.0370329600 0.0251607300 0.0470581700 6.559935e-05  0
```

**sample data used**

[image]